# Как с помощью python скачать файл по JavaScript ссылке?

Tags: python, парсер

пытаюсь с сайта СПб-биржи скачать файл при помощи python.

[Страница с ссылкой (скачать CSV)](https://spbexchange.ru/ru/listing/securities/list/)

На сайте тег ссылки выглядит так:

```html
<a id="ctl00_BXContent_list_LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$BXContent$list$LinkButton1','')">Скачать CSV (разделители - точка с запятой)</a>
```

В ссылке - JS-код. Я попробовал скомпроментировать post-запрос, который вычитал сниффером, копируя все заголовки и данные. Но сервер выдаёт страницу html, а не файл. Стоит отметить, что токены и прочие данные при повторном нажатии не изменяются.

Помогите разобраться!

Answer (score 0):

Итак, проблема решилась. При копроментировании запроса, я не учёл cookies.

Если вам необходимо получить файл или другие данные по такой ссылке (`<a href=javascript:...`)  необходимо:

- Запустить сниффер (например, wireshark)
- Нажать на ссылку вручную, чтобы отловить запрос, выполняемый при клике на ссылку, сниффером
- Скомпроментировать (скопировать) выполняемый запрос, **УЧИТЫВАЯ ВСЕ ЗАГОЛОВКИ, КУКИ И ПЕРЕДАВАЕМЫЕ ДАННЫЕ В ТЕЛЕ ЗАПРОСА.** Если выясняется, что данные могут меняться (например, токен валидации генерируется повторно при перезагрузке страницы) - парсить страницу с ссылкой и вытягивать из неё изменяемые данные перед выполнением запроса.